# Remove Duplicate Value From Nested Array

Tags: php

I have duplicated record from in my array as follow

```
   Array ( [0] => 
              Array ( 
                [driverId] => 112 
                [amount] => 15 
                [firstname] => Katty 
                )
           [1]=>
              Array ( 
                [driverId] => 112 
                [amount] => 15 
                [firstname] => Katty 
                )
           [2]=>
              Array ( 
                [driverId] => 118 
                [amount] => 15 
                [firstname] => Starkj 
                )
)
```

I want to remove with driverId so that my array will not have duplicated result. I tried with array_unique but it is unsuccessful. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`array_unique()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) if you use the `SORT_REGULAR` flag like so:

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

> 5.2.9     Added the optional sort_flags defaulting to SORT_REGULAR. Prior to 5.2.9, this function used to sort the array with SORT_STRING
>   internally.

***Test Results***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php


$array = array(
    array('driverId'=>112,'amount'=>15,'firstname'=>'Katty'),
    array('driverId'=>112,'amount'=>15,'firstname'=>'Katty'),
    array('driverId'=>118,'amount'=>15,'firstname'=>'Starkj')
);

print_r( array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR) );

?>
```

***Output***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [driverId] => 112
            [amount] => 15
            [firstname] => Katty
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [driverId] => 118
            [amount] => 15
            [firstname] => Starkj
        )

)
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Got it from a post

```
$priceList= array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $priceList)));
```

Hope it will help.